# I am sure that he passed the exam. (What's the "that clause"?)

Tags: parts-of-speech

I am sure that he passed the exam. (What's the "that clause"?)

Is that clause "the ojbect" of the adjective "sure"?

the same as in "I am afraid that I can't go there."

Answer (score 1):

Adjectives don't have objects, but the "that" clause is the **complement** of the adjective *sure*.